# How can I DeleteDuplicates in this output list?

Tags: list-manipulation

In this code, I use `DeleteDuplicates`, but I still get Duplicates in Output.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = {1, -3};
b = {3 t + m, 4  t + n};
list = {a + (b - a) k, d, b} /. 
  DeleteDuplicates[
   Solve[{EuclideanDistance[a, b] == d, -5 <= n <= 5, -5 <= m <= 
      5, -8 <= t <= 8, 3 t + m != 1, 4 t + n != -3, 1 <= d <= 10, 
     m  n  t != 0}, {m, n, t, d}, Integers]]
```

[image]

How can I detelte Duplicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the order. Apply the replacement then DeleteDuplicate. Not the other way around.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a = {1, -3};
b = {3  t + m, 4   t + n};
sol = Solve[{EuclideanDistance[a, b] == d, -5 <= n <= 5, -5 <= m <= 
    5, -8 <= t <= 8, 3  t + m != 1, 4  t + n != -3, 1 <= d <= 10, 
   m   n   t != 0}, {m, n, t, d}, Integers];
DeleteDuplicates[{a + (b - a)  k, d, b} /. sol]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Without changing your code too much:

```
list = {a + (b - a) k, d, b} /. 
   Solve[{EuclideanDistance[a, b] == d, -5 <= n <= 5, -5 <= m <= 
      5, -8 <= t <= 8, 3 t + m != 1, 4 t + n != -3, 1 <= d <= 10, 
     m n t != 0}, {m, n, t, d}, Integers] // DeleteDuplicates
```